# Anime with girls who have items that give them powers. One girl becomes a ninja who uses big shears as a weapon

Tags: story-identification, anime, magic, magical-items

I need to find an anime I watched a few years ago.

I don't remember much about the plot but I remember some of the characters' abilities. I think characters in this anime have items that give them powers? And maybe they're kinda like magical girls in a sense. One girl becomes a ninja who I think uses big shears, like the ones used for sewing, as a weapon. I don't remember these ones entirely, but more info is that there's one Cinderella girl and one girl who has an alcohol gourd which gives her boxer powers or something?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What year was "a few years ago?"  Where did you see this?

Comment: If you have a look at the list of anime results on the Shear Meance page in TV Tropes you may recognise something, https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ShearMenace

Comment: im not sure how long it is ago i think maybe around 4 or 5 years? and honestly at this point im starting to believe the anime never even existed  chatgpt or bing chat cant tell what it is either (one character ehere i think an antagonist had a the fool card but i dont think it was shown much so i didnt mention it)

Comment: What do you mean by "Cinderella girl?" Glass slipper weapons? Can command mine minions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Akame_ga_Kill!_characters matches for magic weapons, with one woman having giant scissors, but no gourds that I can see.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly [Negima!?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negima!%3F), the anime that's an alternate retelling of the Negima! series? The series follows the girls of class 2A and their teacher, the titular Negima (a ten year old magician). By performing a [pactio](https://negima.fandom.com/wiki/Pactio) (a magical contract) with him they gain a card symbolising their pact, and a magical artefact that comes with the pactio card. Negima!? has Neo-Pactios instead, which can give three outcomes (a dud card, a cosplay card and an armour card).

Kaede is a ninja, and her neo-pactio armour card has a set of crossed swords on the back. Her pactio artifact from the first anime, Negima!, is a giant shuriken.

[image]

Kuu Fei is adept in Chinese martial arts, and her cosplay card has her as a "drunken master" with an alcohol gourd.

[image]

Comment: Where are the big shears?

Comment: hm i dont think its that because i dont remember it having old artstyle